# Extraction of required words from a string using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

```
  if (txt.matches("Who is the(.*)")) {
        String re1=".*?";   
        String re2="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re3=".*?";
        String re4="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re5=".*?";   
        String re6="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re7=".*?";   
        String re8="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; 
        String re9=".*?";   
        String re10="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  
        String re11=".*?";  
        String re12="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
        if (m.find())
        {
            String word1=m.group(1);
            String word2=m.group(2);
            String z=word2.toString()+"&&"+word1.toString();
            System.out.println(z);
    }
    }
```

I got this code from net but did not understand the code as to how it extracts the few required words from a string "txt". Specially what is this re1 and re2...so on. For any thing as-"Who is the HOD of ECE" it returns ECE&&HOD. Can someone please explain the code...please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments in code to explain what this code does.  All the `re1` and `re2` are doing is creating a string, which is then joined in the `Patern.compile()` portion of the code. When you have 2 strings like `String foo = "foo"` and `String bar = "bar"` and you do `String foobar = foo + bar;` the output is `foobar`.

```
 //If the String object "txt" matches the given regex, which in this case is "Who is the(.*)"
  if (txt.matches("Who is the(.*)")) {
        String re1=".*?";   
        String re2="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re3=".*?";
        String re4="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re5=".*?";   
        String re6="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";   
        String re7=".*?";   
        String re8="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))"; 
        String re9=".*?";   
        String re10="(?:[a-z][a-z]+)";  
        String re11=".*?";  
        String re12="((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";


        //this creates a pattern using the above strings.
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9+re10+re11+re12,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);

        //creates matcher object from the String object "txt"
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);

        //m.find() "Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.", if it does...
        if (m.find())
        {
            //m.group "Returns the input subsequence matched by the previous match."
            String word1=m.group(1);
            String word2=m.group(2);
            //creates a string
            String z=word2.toString()+"&&"+word1.toString();
            //prints out string
            System.out.println(z);
    }
    }
```

[Source for quotes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Comment: Please can you say how they are matching the pattern like what is the ".*?" in re1 and "(?:[a-z][a-z]+)" in re2 and how it is to be known how many times this should be repeated like from re1 to re12 for getting the required words. Please explain